# Variance of piecewise defined random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, variance

I have the random variable
\begin{equation}
X = \begin{cases}
0 \;\; &\text{with probability }\frac{1}{2}\\
\exp(\frac{1}{\lambda}) \;\; &\text{with probability }\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
I want to compute the variance of this random variable. I first compute the expected value.
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{2}\cdot 0+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \exp(\frac{1}{\lambda})]=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[\exp(\frac{1}{\lambda})]=\frac{1}{2}\lambda
\end{equation}
Next I want to compute the second moment of $X$.
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]=\mathbb{E}[(\frac{1}{2}\cdot 0+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\exp(\frac{1}{\lambda}))^{2}]=\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{E}[(\exp(\frac{1}{\lambda}))^{2}]=\frac{1}{4}\cdot2\lambda^{2}=\frac{1}{2}\lambda^{2}
\end{equation}
This would give me the variance as,
\begin{equation}
Var(X)=\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^{2}=\frac{1}{4}\lambda^{2}
\end{equation}
My teacher told me that the variance should be equal to $\frac{3}{4}\lambda^{2}$. I believe that this would mean that the second moment should be equal to $\lambda^{2}$, but I can't seem to figure out how I should get that answer. Can someone tell me where I go wrong in my computation?

Comment: Shouldn't $E X^2 = 0.5 * 0^2 + 0.5 *\exp(1/\lambda)^2$? That is, why are you squaring the probabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using $\exp(\frac1 \lambda)$ to mean an exponentially distributed random variable with mean $\lambda$ and variance $\lambda^2$, rather than the value $e^{1/\lambda}$.

If so, then  $E[(\exp(\frac1 \lambda))^2] = Var(\exp(\frac1 \lambda))+(E[\exp(\frac1 \lambda)])^2 =\lambda^2+\lambda^2=2\lambda^2$

which makes $E[X]=\frac12 E[0]+\frac12 E[\exp(\frac1 \lambda)] = \frac12\lambda$

and $E[X^2]=\frac12 E[0^2]+\frac12 E[(\exp(\frac1 \lambda))^2] = 0+\frac12 2\lambda^2= \lambda^2$

and so $Var(X)= E[X^2]-(E[X])^2=\lambda^2-\frac14\lambda^2=\frac34\lambda^2$.